# jQuery ui-grid/block issue

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a three column grid.  The first column contains one button.  The second and third columns contain two buttons each.  The last column buttons are filling their space, but the second column looks dumpy.  How can I get the buttons in the second column to look like those in the third? Here is some code.

```
<div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" data-icon="eye" data-mini="true" OnClick="OnContentClicked"
            CssClass="ui-btn-g" CommandName="View" Text="View"></asp:Button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <asp:Button ID="btnDownloadXML" runat="server" data-icon="arrow-d" data-mini="true"
                OnClick="OnContentClicked" CommandName="DownloadXML" Text="XML" />
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <asp:Button ID="btnDownloadHTML" runat="server" data-icon="arrow-d" data-mini="true"
                OnClick="OnContentClicked" CommandName="DownloadHTML" Text="Readable" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-a ui-responsive">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <asp:Button ID="btnTransmitXML" runat="server" data-icon="mail" data-mini="true"
                OnClick="OnContentClicked" CommandName="TransmitXML" Text="XML"></asp:Button>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <asp:Button ID="btnTransmit" runat="server" data-icon="mail" data-mini="true"
                OnClick="OnContentClicked" CommandName="TransmitHTML" Text="Readable"></asp:Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I placed the buttons for those two columns in a ui-grid-c and they resized perfectly.  Not sure if that's a kludge or not.  If there are any better (or more proper) solutions, please let me know!